# save data to redis and support quick query

Tags: redis

I have a table like below:

```
sec_name  date1 date2 date3
   IBM      10    11    12
   GOO      11     8     7
   AWS       7    14    12
   ALI      12     6     6
```

I want to store them into redis, and support the query to get data by sec_name list and date list, e.g [IBM, AWS]& [date1, date3].

Any better data structure for store in redis?
Assume that there are 10000*10000 data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of performance every `sec_name` should be a key of a Hash data structure, in which each field is a date.

To perform your query you'll need to break it down to multiple calls to `HGET`, one for each security's name.

Comment: @KemmyGuo you're welcome - please mark my answer as correct if it so pleases you :)